# What are the alternatives to having multiple main elements in an html page?

Tags: html, css

My HTML code has got several main elements at once. Those main elements are also affected by some CSS style sheets which give them a border.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
<!-- Here come css which give `main` elements a nice border. -->
<!-- This is a MWE, other attributes may follow. -->
    main { border-style: solid; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
<p>Some text</p>
</main>
<main>
<p>Some more text</p>
</main>
<main>
<p>And another section with some text</p>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

This works well on the browsers that I have tested. But I also know that multiple `mains` are not standard conformant.

What is the best practice that avoids multiple `main` elements as above but otherwise gives *exactly* the same behavior on every browser no matter what else I put into the CSS style sheet?

Comment: Use a `<div>` ?

Comment: One`main`, several `article` or `section` would be appropriate

Comment: So `main`, `div`, and the like are guaranteed to work the same, if for example I just sed everything?

Comment: What standard are you referring to when you say it's not conformant?

Answer (score 0):

Assign your elements names or ids so that within the css you can differentiate which element should display which styles. Here's an example:

```
<! -- this would be your element in the body -->
<div id="mainStyle></div>
```

and in the stylesheet, the style corresponding to that id should be

```
#mainStyle {

     //attributes defined here

}
```

Any element that doesn't have the same id won't be affected